# vba: What is Cells(2, 27).Value = "=元!R[3]C[-26]"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Cells(2, 27).Value = "=元!R[3]C[-26]"
```

Does anybody know what is the meaning of this? I understood this `元!` is the sheet name. But I don't understand the next part. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Relative column? So go form this column (27) to column 27-26, which would give you C1? and just pick R3.

Comment: Hmm.Sorry I don't get it. Could you explain ?

Comment: Check this link http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html

Comment: R refers to Row and C refers to Column.  R[3] means it targets +3 rows from activecell and C[-26] means it targets -26 columns from activecell.

Comment: @Sixthsense write an answer ...

Comment: @Sixthsense How do i know what is the activecell  ?

Comment: @ShaiRado What is the meaning of "元!" in this case

Comment: @ToujouAya `元` is the sheet name, the `!` separates the sheet name from the cell reference, `R[3]` means 3 rows below the cell where the formula exists, `C[-26]` means 26 columns to the left of where the formula exists.  `Cells(2, 27)` is where the formula is being placed, but `.Value` should really be `.FormulaR1C1` (although VBA will probably guess what is meant and treat it correctly anyway).  So after the statement is executed cell AA2 will contain the formula `=元!A5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `元` refers to the sheet (it translates to yuan, which is a unit of the Renmimbi currency in the PRC (mainland China)). The `=<name>!<something>` is the standard way to refer to cells on a specifically-named worksheet.

The rest of it, `R[3]C[-26]`, is the *real* row/column references used by Excel under the covers, not that namby-pamby `A$4`-type stuff that people are fond of.

I suggest you got at look for Joel Spolsky's *excellent* ["You suck at Excel"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nbkaYsR94c) presentation, there's some things of real beauty in there, including an explanation of that format.